# HTML： ふりがな（ruby）を追加するときに行間拡大を少なくする

Tags: html, css

HTMLで`<ruby>`を追加すると、行間が非常に広がる事があります。下記の例のように、行間があまり大きくなったことなく`<ruby>`何とか設定できますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 画像は、好ましい（各行の行間が等しい）例として出されたのだと思い回答したのですが、もしかして悪い（行間がひろすぎる）例として出されていますか？

Comment: 好ましいです。この場合はふりがなが行間に影響しません（画像での本文はLuaLaTeXでレンダリングされました）。しかし、行間が小さいときに、ふりがながある行と前の行の間空間を少し大きくすることが必要になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テキストの行間が、ルビの高さより大きければ、ルビのある行間だけ大きくなる事はありません。
地の文の`line-height`とルビの文字の`font-size`を適切なバランスで設定すればよいです。

質問の画像のテキストは、`line-height`が`1.8em`くらいはありそうです。
行間は`1.8em - 1em`で`0.8em`程度になります。
ルビの文字(`<rt>`)の`font-size`は`0.5em`(日本語組版でのデフォルトのようです)くらいでしょうか。
`0.8em - 0.5em = 0.3em` で、`0.3em`程度の余裕がある事になります。

```css
h1{ font-size: 1em; }

#low{ line-height: 1em; }

#just{ line-height: 1.5em; }

#high{ line-height: 2.25em; }

[id] rt{ font-size: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<h1>ルビ無し(ブラウザデフォルト)</h1>
<p>
一行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。<br />
二行目。アイウエオ。カキクケコ。
<br />
三行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。
</p>
                                                                                      
<h1>ブラウザデフォルト</h1>
<p>
一行目。 あいうえお。かきくけこ。<br />
<ruby>二行目<rp>(</rp><rt>にぎょうめ</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>。アイウエオ。カキクケコ。
<br />
三行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。
</p>
                                                                                      
<h1>行間せまめ</h1>
<p id="low">
一行目。 あいうえお。かきくけこ。<br />
<ruby>二行目<rp>(</rp><rt>にぎょうめ</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>。アイウエオ。カキクケコ。
<br />
三行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。
</p>
                                                                                      
<h1>ぴったり</h1>
<p id="just">
一行目。 あいうえお。かきくけこ。<br />
<ruby>二行目<rp>(</rp><rt>にぎょうめ</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>。アイウエオ。カキクケコ。
<br />
三行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。
</p>
                                                                                      
<h1>行間ひろめ</h1>
<p id="high">
一行目。 あいうえお。かきくけこ。<br />
<ruby>二行目<rp>(</rp><rt>にぎょうめ</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>。アイウエオ。カキクケコ。
<br />
三行目。あいうえお。かきくけこ。
</p>
```